# Nice HTML Slidder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would need a slidder similar to what can be found in the [HP page](http://www.hp.com/).
Is there any similar Script. I've done something but jquery-1.7.2.min but is a bit too simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about jQuery's own slider: [Slider](http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/28-useful-jquery-sliders-you-need-to-download/)
Which you apply to an element like this `$("#slider").slider();`

Or any one of these sliders: [28 useful sliders](http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/28-useful-jquery-sliders-you-need-to-download/)

Comment: -1 SO is not a URL suggestions site.